# How to save/load data Online(Store data with AJAX and JSON) and Offline (locally)

Tags: android, ios, load, save, offline

I need help figuring out the best, cross-browser compatible way to "SAVE" user input and STORE them locally(offline mod) AND on a server(online).  Program will be used by Android and iOS.

I want to know the best way to track user progress while the device is online OR offline.

Hello I have been researching AJAX, JSON, XMLHttpRequest, REST, Java, and HTML5 (specifically, localStorage).

**The scenario: (Read a book online/offline, save page progress)**

1. A user logs in to a Web Service and the Web Service allows the user to download an "html webpage book" (view with HTML5 browser).
2. After every page turn, a REST API uses a GET request to post the Progress data to a Web Server. Simultaneously, a JSON string is created and saved in a file on the server. (let's say "ProgressData.txt")
3. In the background, a separate "copy" of ProgressData.txt is saved LOCALLY on the mobile device. The user then leaves the internet connection and continues to read the HTML Book.
4. When the user regains connectivity, the ProgressData.txt is uploaded to the server using a REST API where it will update the old server file with the NEW .txt file with all of the user ProgressData.

**Possible solutions:**

HTML5 localStorage solution looks good. jQuery even simplifies it:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/html5Storage

Straight Javascript looks good for Server-Side storage, however it doesn't have access to a mobile device's physical hard-drive, thus preventing any kind of offline saving.

Java applets look possible.  Plus not sure how Java runs with Android/iOS.

I don't want to have to run a localhost(PHP/Apache/Python) from a mobiledevice every time the user goes offline, however that may be where the solution lies. I did stumble on this powerful tool: http://couchdb.apache.org/

**Question:**

I need to know the best way to track user progress while the device is online OR offline.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Scott, did you find anything?

Comment: @Flakerim, I have spent the past month playing with javascript, php, even Java, looking for simple, cross browser compatible solutions to the "online/offline db sync" problem. 
My conclusion is this: 
1. Use Javascript to capture all data you need to store.

Comment: 2. When online, post all data to a server using PHP curl functions (or something similar...possibly Ruby on Rails).
3. During all browsing (online or offline), save all data locally using either cookies or html5 web storage.

Comment: hmmm, I think CouchDB is the answer, but it has to be installed on Client side, as far as I know. I need Couch because I want to save more than a book page number. Plus, I need to access it from server side, So if connection came while user has not opened client, I want to sync them, and after user opens client its all synced Already. I need to have a db that doesn't need to install and can access from HTTP. Like a text file in web root or mdb or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 screencasts what will help you with your problem.

They are in Ruby on Rails but maybe you can get the idea. It is using the html5 cache manifest.

Hope it will help you!

http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/248-offline-apps-part-2

some more resources (sorry i dont have experiences myself with html5 cache manifest)

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Comment: Rails casts looks promising!!

Comment: I checked out Rails and I agree with @Flakerim, definitely something to look into. Hopefully soon. 

I am also playing around with cashe manifest, and concluded it provides a workable alternative to cookies, but limits users to HTML 5 browsers. This site also has some good HTML 5 cashe stuff. http://introducinghtml5.com/

Comment: I am afraid it is kind of hard to do it with all the browsers... Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) the other day which might help solve the cross browser local storage. It was from [this article](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/04/using-client-side-storage-today/) about local storage.

I think your best option for tracking online/offline is to ping the server via an AJAX call when the page is turned. Always try and update the server on a page turn, but if it fails, handle the failure and store the progress locally. Each page turn will either amend the locally stored progress file or if connection is restored then simply update the server with the progress.

The issue I am thinking might occur is if a book is finished offline then there are no more clicks that would trigger the syncing, regardless of a restored connection. You may want to think about a manual sync link/button at the end of a book. Or maybe have a manual sync available at all times anyway? Give some control to the users and describe the whole offline/online reading scenario. You might find that it is easier to just let the users do the work… if they don't sync then it's their problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just using a cookie to store the current state.  That way it is automatically sent to your server with every user request (so no need to build out a custom server-side API for receiving the state after a lost connection, and no need to have any custom client-side code for sending the data to the server), and still updateable even if the user has lost Internet connectivity.  Also it doesn't rely on HTML5 features, so you don't need to restrict people to HTML5-capable browsers.

In any case, the best way to handle storing the current state would be to have a simple `onclick` handler on your "next page" link (or button, or whatever it is) that calls a function and sets the cookie value to whatever the current position is.  Note that because the state is always available client-side, and sent to the server on every request, there is no need to maintain any explicit copy of the state server-side, unless you want to be able to remember the user's place even when they manually delete their cookies (which is overkill in my opinion).

You may want to look at the [W3C Example Code](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for setting/getting cookie values in JavaScript.

Also, here's a [website](http://webcomix.no-ip.org/) that demonstrates functionality similar to what you want to build.  It uses cookies to keep track of a user's place when reading various webcomics.  Pretty much the same as what it sounds like you want, except with comics instead of books.

Comment: What I need is: If connection is offline, save to local, when it gets online sync with master db.

Comment: @Flakerim - That's basically what this gives you.  If you want to maintain real-time sync with the server then just add a bit of code so that whenever the cookie's value changes a new request is sent to the server, and set up the error handler for the request such that if the request fails it tries again after some reasonable delay (like 60 seconds).  Or you can do it the simpler but less efficient way, and just fire off a request every 60 seconds (using `setInterval`, for instance) to ensure that the server always has the latest state information.

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to track the progress in both a server side database and in the client's local storage if a constant internet connection is not necessary.

Evercookie is a controversial javascript api that aims to provide local storage using any means available including standard cookies, Flash shared object, Silverlight, browser history and HTML 5 storage.  Data should persist when the user is offline and when the connection is restored, sync the cookie and database with whichever data has greater page number for the given book.  Droid has Flash and the Flash shared object data is a "cookie" available to both desktop and web-based apps.

With great power comes great responsibility:
http://samy.pl/evercookie/